# Python Package does not have package_data

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am new to python and trying to package my python code using below command.

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

**Problem:** The utilites directory is not part of the package. I am not able to import from modules in utilitites directory when I install this package.

**Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

```
PPBL/
    setup.py
    PPBL/
        __init__.py
        RPA/
            __init__.py
            UiHelper.py
        utilities/
            logger_utility.py
            config_utility.py
```

**Setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

VERSION = '0.0.1'
DESCRIPTION = 'RPA Tool'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'RPA automation tool'

# Setting up
setup(
    # the name must match the folder name
    name="PPBL",
    version=1,
    author="xyz",
    author_email="xyz@gmail.com",
    description="RPA Automation",
    long_description="RPA Automation",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        "PPBL": ["utilites/*", "resources/*"],  # Adjust package name and folder structure
    },
    install_requires=[
        "selenium==4.11.2",
        "openpyxl==3.1.2",
    ],
    keywords=['python', 'first package'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: In-Progress",
    ]
)
```

Comment: Also, I observed the when I install this package and try to import from Browser subpackage. I can import like RPA.Browser not using Parent Package PPBL.RPA.Browser.